# You [adjective] vs you are [adjective]

Tags: word-usage, slang

I've been wondering, why sometimes you don't say the verb in sentences, like "you stupid" instead of "you're stupid" or even "you are stupid"? What does it change? Is this make your sentence slang if you don't say the verb? And it doesn't work with every sentences, right?

Comment: What variety of English are you referring to? There is no doubt this is typical of at least one type or other of American English; is it American you're thinking of?

Comment: Dropping "is" and "are" is common in dialects such as [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English) and parts of the southern US, but very nonstandard in others. Where are you? Who are you speaking to? Is this formal speech or chatting with your friends?

Comment: Person One "Who did you say left the mess in the kitchen?" Person Two: "You, stupid".

Comment: In American English, you can say: "You, stupid" to mean "you are the one, you stupid person" or as a form of abusive address to mean "You are the one I am addressing, you stupid person."  You can also say "stupid!" to meant "that was just a stupid thing to say or do."  You can also say: "You stupid idiot/fool/etc." as a form of abusive address; however, you cannot grammatically say "you stupid" in standard English as form of abusive address.  As is said below, particularly in African American vernacular English, it is fine to say "You stupid." as the equivalent of "You are stupid."

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your explanations! I was just talking about English in general but I think that @Vegawatcher answered to all of my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variety of motivations and traditions produces phrasing that omits a verb in sentences such as "You are stupid."

• It's 'cool' (trendy) to drop words. It makes the speaker and those who understand him part of a private-jargon group.

• Simplified sentences are common in speech directed at babies and pets. "You so sweet! You good boy!" This just seems to be human nature.

• Dropping verbs is also sometimes done in imitation of non-native speakers, who may be more likely to leave out some words in complex sentences. It's also a comedic stereotype: the Asian character who says, "You no funny! You bad man", instead of "You're not funny! You are a bad man!"

It's definitely slang-ish to drop a verb in a "you are x" sentence. However, it's not slang to drop verbs, subjects, and other parts of speech in many other cases: signs, article headlines, epigrams, poetry, and so on.